# jquery formValidator with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery ui FormValidator (live). For the e-mail address, beside syntax and requirement, I need to check via php if the e-mail address is already in use. I can't get it work with ajax, because of callback and asynchronous issues, that's what I have understood so far. 
First, my formValidator Snippet for the e-mail part:

```
[...]                  ,
                emailaddress: {
                    rules: {
                        regEx: "email",
                        required: true,
                        custom: function (mailaddressvalue) {
                                // need return true or false of ajax result here
                                }
                    },
[...]
```

At the "custom" section, the use of the e-mail address should be checked via ajax, need "true" or "false" only as result.
The ajax function should be something like this:

```
function checkMailEntry(mailaddress){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'mailcheck.php',
                cache: false,
                data: "mailvalue="+mailaddress+"",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html'
            });

        }
```

Even with a callback function, I can't get the result of the ajax function. Any help would be appreciated! If you need more information or a fiddle, just let me know.

Thanks in Advance,
Matty

Comment: which is the plugin used here?

Comment: this one http://fnagel.github.io/jQuery-Accessible-RIA/Formular/index.html